# AWS user with "AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess" gets "User is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Every post on "User is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource" from amazon's **lambda** leads to the same repeatedly stated answer and lots of cheerful reply after the following fix applied:

> Add the appropriate permissions to the IAM role assigned to the Lambda function.

Apparently it is not enough:

"An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the PutItem operation: User: arn:aws:sts::759832573084:assumed-role/operator/get-orders is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-southeast-2:759832573084:table/queue"

The IAM role assigned to the Lambda function here I believe is the user 'operator', who has:

- AWSLambdaFullAccess
- AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
- AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole
- AmazonDynamoDBFullAccesswithDataPipeline

As you can see I oversupplied 'operator' user permissions in order to overcome the problem.

Other things I checked are:

- The error is reproducible in the AWS console's lambda debugger
- The table 'queue' has a Amazon Resource Name the same as stated in the error message.
- Lambda is created in the same region (Asia Pacific 2) as the dynamodb table.
- lambda documents mentioned that for fine-tuning permission on the table, its primary key has to be a string, so I changed my table 'queue' primary key to a string. Didn't help.

Don't think it's relevant but the language used in the lambda is Python 3.6

Comment: Do you "believe is the user 'operator'"? Can you, please, check what value you have on console, on Lambda "Execution role" panel?

Comment: *"the user `operator`"* is not a **user,** it's an IAM Role.  When a role is assumed, there is a transient instance of an identity (called a "user" in the error message) created with temporary credentials that carry the role's permissions.  If you also have an IAM user named `operator`, that is an unrelated entity, but could be the cause of the confusion.

Comment: @michael-sqlbot It turns out that this is exactly the cause. The user 'operator' has all needed permissions but the role 'operator' doesn't. So the problem is fixed.